# How to make Magento customer registration and login in ajax popup window outside the main site.?

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, magento-1.9, registration

I have a Magento site, and one part of the site is separate from the main site.(main: example.com and separate: example.com/test)

I need to make an ajax popup login and register for that page without refresh the page.

I found many articles but no-one mention for outside the main site.

**The folder structure is:**

- HTML

  - app(main site)
  - test(separate folder)

best I need is coding than extension.If you suggest extension please clearly mention the way of configuring to outside of the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this is to create a (local) Magento module which has its own URL, controller action and template. This would allow the code to be executed inside the application. Is there a reason you're trying to set this up outside of the app folder?

If you really need to do it this way, look at the Magento index.php. This file is an example of initializing a new Magento instance. You will need to create a login form which submits the data to a PHP file that instantiates Magento and calls the login action.

It may also be possible to use a pop-up modal that uses the Magento login URL. As long as it routes the request through the index.php, Magento will be initialized and the task should be performed.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Magento, Can you clearly mention, please?

Comment: Can you explain your use case so I can better understand and suggest a solution? I'm not sure why you are trying to build this outside the app folder and how it's going to be used.

Comment: This is a custom editor for some product material. after the design, it's going to add to cart for purchase the design. example: castify.com custom case designer. customer click on continue its ask a login or register! Got it my point.?